# How to output the process.stderr.write to winston

Tags: node.js, express, winston

Using winston loggers to write contents into the files but that works only when `customlogger.error` is used. If the node is outputting some reference error like below

```
ReferenceError: aksbd is not defined
at /home/nigilan/Desktop/homepagelogger/app.js:53:20
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/nigilan/Desktop/homepagelogger/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/home/nigilan/Desktop/homepagelogger/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (/home/nigilan/Desktop/homepagelogger/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/nigilan/Desktop/homepagelogger/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /home/nigilan/Desktop/homepagelogger/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (/home/nigilan/Desktop/homepagelogger/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
at next (/home/nigilan/Desktop/homepagelogger/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
at /home/nigilan/Desktop/homepagelogger/app.js:38:5
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/nigilan/Desktop/homepagelogger/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

How to use winston to store the errors like above ?

P.S. Logging the unhandled exception is nodejs server is working fine.

Comment: This code is working fine , but winston would be very helpful.  

process.stderr.write = function (message) {
  fs.appendFile('k.log', message, function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  });
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
`
function formatArgs(args){
    return [util.format.apply(util.format, Array.prototype.slice.call(args))];
}
console.info = function(){
    customlogger.info.apply(customlogger, formatArgs(arguments));
};
console.warn = function(){
    customlogger.warn.apply(customlogger, formatArgs(arguments));
};`
```

Here you can also use the default logger of winston instead of your custom logger. The gist code below has the perfect answer for [this](https://gist.github.com/spmason/1670196).